# Why for...in... doesn't work in this list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
mylist = [1, 2, 34, j]
for x in mylist:
    if type(x) == int:
        print "Number:", x
    elif type(x) == str:
        print "Word:", x
    else:
        raise Error
```

This code doesn't work - NameError: 'j' is not defined.

Why statement `for... in...` doesn't work with the list containing both integers and strings?

Comment: `j` is not a string, it is an unitialized variable. Should be `mylist = [1, 2, 34, 'j']`

Comment: Comment everything out after the first line. What happens? Revisit the assumption/question.

Comment: Look carefully at the traceback. Which line has the error?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have not defined any variable `j` , but you are trying to use it in `mylist` . Its not that `for..in` does not work, the issue is in the line before that, where you are defining the list. You want to use `'j'` (in quotes) for string, instead of `j`. Example -

```
mylist = [1, 2, 34, 'j']
for x in mylist:
    if type(x) == int:
        print "Number:", x
    elif type(x) == str:
        print "Word:", x
    else:
        raise Error
```

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```
mylist = [1, 2, 34, "j"]
```